# OnClick HTML button : call Javascript function + location.href (Django)

Tags: javascript, html, django, button, onclick

How can I put 2 operations in my onclick parameter, one calling a Javascript function, the other giving location.href with Django tags ? I want to make something appear on the page before redirecting to another page.

I want to do something like this :

```
onclick="chargement();location.href='{% url 'resumefic' upload.0.pk %}';"
```

but my function `chargement()`isn't called, only the redirection works.

I can't put the location.href in a JS function as I'm using Django tags...
Can someone help ?

Comment: Maybe because of the scope?  Try window.location.href?

Comment: This should work normally... Have you tried to open the browser JS console? Maybe something failed during the execution of `chargement()` function.

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude Yep but nothing appears in the console (although I put some console.log to check), looks like it doesn't pass in it...

Comment: That's strange. And if you remove the `location.href=...` thing the function is called?

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude Yes !

Comment: Try `onclick="chargement();" href='{% url 'resumefic' upload.0.pk %}'`

Comment: Wait, in your post what do you mean by "this isn't working"? Nothing happens at all, or are you at least redirected?

Comment: @MaxM My function `chargement()` is called but it doesn't redirect to the url...

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude Yep I'm redirected ! I just can't manage to have both operations done, either one or the other is working. Sorry for the bad explanations

Comment: Pass you're URL to your method: `onclick="chargement({% url 'resumefic' upload.0.pk %});"` and handle it there.

Comment: Ok, I thing I know what is the problem. I'll post an answer below.

Comment: It worked like this @MaxM, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the redirection occurs before you can see what the `chargement` function has done. Try adding a delay before the redirection, for example replace your code with.

```
onclick="chargement();setTimeout(function(){location.href='{% url 'resumefic' upload.0.pk %}';},1000);"
```